# SKErrorDomain error 5 with SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

Facing **SKErrorDomain error 5** when trying to open app with **SKStoreProductViewController** logic.
The build has been done with Unity, I integrated my custom library with this feature. Using Xcode 12.5, don't have expected behavior on all iOS versions.

What am I doing wrong and maybe it is some settings I have to change in Xcode project?

Code:

```
            storeControllersaved = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
            storeControllersaved.delegate = self;
            NSDictionary *parameters = @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[Itunesid intValue]]};
            [storeControllersaved loadProductWithParameters:parameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Log Error %@",  error.localizedDescription);
        }
        if (result) {
                [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:storeControllersaved animated:YES completion:^{
                }];
            
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NOT LOADED");
            }
        }
    }];
```